# Unable to connect 2 layouts to a single Scrollable layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have those 2 layouts, I am trying to make out of those 2 a scrollable layout, I tried everything (I am not publishing my tries because I don't want to overload with code). Everything I tried always partially worked, always one of the layout weren't displayed correctly... I also tried to connect them with "include layout" but that didn't work well and cause the number picker to disappear. I am trying for hours that thing that should be so simple, I really can't understand why it doesn't work. Note: "GameContentET" should be expendable properly, and the second layout simply contains 8 EdiTexts in a row. first layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"><TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
   android:text="Title"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/numberPicker2"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/GameTitleET"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/GameTitleET"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Text1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/GameContentET"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberPicker2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/GameContentET"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="267dp"
    android:hint="TextBox2"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GameTitleET"</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Design:
[image: Design of first Layout]

This is the second layout: (Very simple, 8 EditTexts one after another)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodTitleET1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/TitleOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodContentET1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:hint="@string/ContentOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodTitleET1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodTitleET2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/TitleOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/MethodContentET2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodContentET1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodContentET2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ContentOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodTitleET2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodTitleET3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/TitleOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodContentET2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodContentET3"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/ContentOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodTitleET3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodTitleET4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/TitleOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MethodContentET3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/MethodContentET4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:hint="@string/ContentOfMethod"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Design:[image: Design of the second layout]

I want to do the simplest thing and combine them to one scrollable layout, preferably through "include" but at this point anything that will work will do.
I hope you could guide and help me to get there, Thank you!

Comment: Why didn't you put all these things together in a single `ScrollView`?

Comment: it doesn't work...